# How to move files from C Drive to a Network Drive in Python?

Tags: python, shutil

This is a follow up to a previous question I asked.

I have been automating a web process using python and selenium and the end result is several downloaded files. They are automatically downloaded to my C: drive in the downloads folder.

I wanted to move the files from the C: Drive to the Z: Drive. However, the Z drive is a network drive. It is my understanding that Python cannot inherently move files to a network drive.

When I run this script:

```
source_dir = "C:\\Users\\e1206433\\Downloads\\EstadisticaEjecGlo*.csv\\"
dest_temp = "Z:\\AN\\Produban\\Operations\\"


for file in glob.glob(source_dir):
    shutil.move(source_dir, dest_temp)

print (source_dir) 
#Printing source_dir to ensure the script is reaching the shutil command
```

The terminal returns the following:

```
C:\Users\e1206433\Downloads\EstadisticaEjecGlo*.csv\

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This suggests that the command is successfulyl moving the files. 
However when I check the source directory, the files are still there and have not been moved to the file in the network drive.

Can anyone explain how to solve this issue?

Many Thanks.

Comment: The computer you're running the from, it has access to the network drive, correct?

Comment: "It is my understanding that Python cannot inherently move files to a network drive" - that's true of the normal OS move-by-renaming, but not a specific Python limitation I don't think? However [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) should fall back to shutil.copy2 in this case, so should work.

Comment: @CapnJack Yeah, the network drive is mapped on my computer and I have access to it.

Comment: Is it the trailing slash in your source_dir? I'd guess your files are `.csv` not `.csv\ ` ? Or are these actually directories called EstadisticaEjecGlo*.csv that you want to recursively copy?

Comment: @Rup this is a company network drive - is it possible that the drive has permissions preventing shutil.move from working? However, I would have expected a permissions error if this was the case.

Comment: See @Rup 's comment, also is the `glob.glob` here necessary in the for loop?

Comment: shutil.move specifically? I doubt it, it would just look like normal writes to the filesystem.

Comment: So I removed the trailing slashes and Now have [WinError123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. @Rup

Comment: I am using the glob.glob as the end of the file names are wildcards, the suffix changes each download, and i believe that glob.glob moves wild cards. @CapnJack

Answer (score 1):

In the method `shutil.move` you use `source_dir`, try to change for `file`.
And delete the `\\` after `*.csv`

```
source_dir = "C:\\Users\\e1206433\\Downloads\\EstadisticaEjecGlo*.csv"
dest_temp = "Z:\\AN\\Produban\\Operations\\"


for file in glob.glob(source_dir):
    shutil.move(file, dest_temp)

print (source_dir) 
#Printing source_dir to ensure the script is reaching the shutil command
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I have removed the \\ and I also replaced the source_dir for file and it returned a this error: OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive

Comment: This error is throw for `os.rename()` did you change the method?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, but no, I'm still using shutil.move